# OpenCl.vim file error

Tags: vim, opencl

I have started working on Opencl for a project. I have wanted to use my favorite editor vim for my development and downloaded a opencl.vim file from vim.org and have placed in syntax directory of vim.

When i try to open any .cl file i get this error from vim. Can some one please help me with this:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/opencl.vim:
line    5:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
line    6:
E15: Invalid expression: version < 600^M
line  159:
E171: Missing :endif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the file is using DOS format line endings (evidenced by `^M`).  Run a `dos2unix` utility on the file to convert it to UNIX line endings:

```
dos2unix /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/opencl.vim
```

(Make a backup copy first to be safe)

Comment: thanks michael.. did not realize that i have edited this file on XP machine before keeping it on my linux box.

Comment: This seems to be a common occurrence when downloading the opencl.vim file from the website(http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3157). Looks like the file was made with DOS format line endings because I'm using Ubuntu.